# PHP Copy-Paste Detector

Tags: php, pear

My problem is that when I run [phpcpd](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd) command I always get 0% doubled code result, no matter if it's my project, if it's any php module's files, or if it's a file I created to check if phpcpd works...For example when I check the file below it also displays 0%:

phpcpd folder/file.php:

```
<?php

class Class_Two {

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }   

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }
    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

}

class Class_Two {

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

    public function aaa()
    {
        if(2 == 2)
        {
            echo 'ok';
        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions on why isn't it working properly? Or maybe it is supposed to do some other tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it on a folder not a file:

```
phpcpd /folder/
```

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.codediesel.com/tools/detecting-duplicate-code-in-php-files/

> By default phpcpd will search for a minimum of 5 identical lines and
>   70 identical tokens. So if there are less than 5 duplicate lines in
>   the code or less than 70 identical tokens they will be ignored. To
>   override this you can use the –min-lines and –min-tokens switch.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I tried both, and none works...I mean I always get 0 doubled lines even if I make a lot of the same lines in a file. 
When I type --min-lines 1 --min-tokens 1 however I get two notices: Undefined offset in C:/php/pear/PHPCPD/Detector/Strategy/Default.php on line 106...